# Help with clicking too fast

Tags: jquery, click

I have setup a custom scroll and everything is working great only issue i am having is if people click really fast they can make it skip the end point.

is their anyway to get around this here is my demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/WTu4r/9/

it will work fine to 3/3 if you click slowly but if you click really fast it skips.

any help pls

Comment: It looks to me like your code is WAY too complicated for what you are trying to achieve, anyway you should count how many times you can scroll and check if it doesn't go over that number.

Comment: This looks like a design issue where you loose your pointer (it, they step outside of the bounds that they should be contained in, ie: 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Sorry this is my first attempt at a jquery plugin any suggestions on improvements thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is already animating then just return from the function without doing anything. Don't update the page numbers also. Something like this.

```
if($("elementSelector").is(":animated")){
   return;
}
```

Comment: Hi Shankar i have drop if($("ul#scrollBlogger").is(":animated")){
      alert('animating');
        return;
     } into the plugin but it doesnt alert when its animating???

Comment: Are you sure you are animating `$("ul#scrollBlogger")` in the plugin?

Comment: HI i got it working with the following if($("#scrollBlogger:animated").length == 0){ // i run the code here }

Comment: Is `#scrollBlogger` an `ul` element?

Comment: If it is not an ul element then you should just say `if($("#scrollBlogger").is(":animated")){ }`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2777/discussion-between-dchp-and-shankarsangoli)